# Simple CRUD won't create Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried to get into rails and ruby by starting to work on a little project and have a problem I can't get around.

As I was trying to create a simple CRUD for an Object, the creation part made no sense anymore.

```
def create
    if (params.nil? || params[:board].nil?)
        return render status: 400
    end
    @board = Board.create(params["board"]["title"], params["board"]["description"])
    #...
end
```

For whatever reason, it gives me an **ArgumentError "wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)"**. So I thought I'll simply create it myself and use the save-Method to save it into the database, but that didn't work out either:

```
@board = Board.new(params["board"]["title"], params["board"]["description"])
@board.save!
```

This gives me the **NoMethodError "undefined method `reverse_merge!' for nil:NilClass"**.

I tried allot of debugging now but can't figure it out. And not, it's not nil, even though it's saying it's using the NilClass.

EDIT: Form Code (View)

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' do %>

<div class="fluid-container">
    <p><label for="board_title">Title</label></p>
    <%= text_field 'board', 'title' %>
</div>

<div class="fluid-container">
    <p><label for="board_description">Description</label></p>
    <%= text_area 'board', 'description' %>
</div>

<%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

I really don't know what's going on, hopefully someone can help. Thanks in advance - PreFiX/Dominik

Comment: please post your form code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@board = Board.create(params["board"]["title"], params["board"]["description"])
```

try

```
 @board = Board.create(title: params["board"]["title"], description: params["board"]["description"])
```

You should be able to do this too

```
@board = Board.create(params[:board])
```

but for security reasons that wont work 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

Comment: Already tried that as well, gives out **NoMethodError: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"**

Comment: Sorry was just editing - can you try Board.create(title: params["board"]["title"], description: params["board"]["description"]) and then read the note on Parameters. For security reasons you can pass in bulk parameters

Comment: Does this work: Board.create(title: "the title", description: "the description")

Answer (score 0):

When you try to create a new object, you should pass a hash and not strings like you did.

Replace your controller method to

```
def create
  @board = Board.new(board_params)

  if @board.save
    redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.'
  else
    # render the new page
  end
end
```

And add a private method

```
private 

def board_params
  params.require(:board).permit(:title, :description)
end
```

Comment: Sadly also returns into a **NoMethodError: "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"**

Comment: @PreFiXAUT It looks like params is nil. Can you replace the content of your controller method to `render text: params["board"]` and tell me what gets displayed when you click on `Save Post`?

Comment: It only outputs a sinlge '#', that's all. The weird aspect is that I rendered the show directly to see if there's actually data and there is and I was able to create a board, but not to save it sadly.

Comment: @PreFiXAUT Your code is working fine for me. I don't get you. If you try to save without entering any values, you should see `{"title"=>"", "description"=>""}` Did you see that? Replace everything in your `create` action to `render text: params["board"]`. Tell me what is rendered.

Comment: I know and from every aspect I look at it it makes NO sense at all. I didn't look the entire source-code before and noticed it returns **actioncontroller::parameters:0x0000000c6fbc40** after the __#__